# Crystal Report DateTime Conversion

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to edit a report for my supervisor. I really have no experience with Crystal Reports but somehow I am the go to man for everything Crystal Reports. What I am working with is a Cross Tab table that shows work orders by date and time. The column is a time field and shows each hour. Right now that field is formatted as only the hour and 24 hour format. But I would like a 12 hour format showing AM/PM. The field uses this formula which I think if I can edit this formula it will do what I need but I have not had much luck in my research.

CStr(Hour(CTime({@dtreqdate})),0)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I got it work i just changed it to CStr({@dtreqdate}, "h tt") and now it is doing what I need